# Accessing BT 2.1 + EDR device via coreBluetooth on iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing an application and try to configure mouse, gamepad and handset. Those BT devices are using BT 4.0 chipset (single mode) and BT3.0/BT4.0 (Dual mode). They both accept GATT protocol.

I would like to know with iOS 5.x - coreBluetooth framework, whether my application has any chance to communicate to BT3.0/BT4.0 device via GATT on iPhone 3GS.

It seems that coreBluetooth would not work on iPhone 3GS as iPhone 3GS does not have BT 4.0 module.

Am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. CoreBluetooth is only for Bluetooth 4.0 (BLE) communications. So it wont work on your 3GS.